Extract data from string column based on delimiter
I have a column with value like this.
Declare @Table TABLE (ID int, Val varchar(100))

Insert into @Table
Select 1, 'happy_Summer_Holiday_by_Jan_2024.xlsx'

I want to dynamically extract  Jan as Month and 2024  as year.

Assuming that the Month and Year are always the last parts of the filename (as in the single example), I would do this.
Declare @Table TABLE (ID int, Val varchar(100))

Insert into @Table
Select 1, 'happy_Summer_Holiday_by_Jan_2024.xlsx'

;WITH CTE_Split AS
    (
    SELECT T.ID
        , T.Val 
        , REVERSE(P.[value]) AS StringPart
        , P.ordinal
    FROM @Table AS T
        OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REVERSE(T.Val), '_', 1) AS P
    )
, CTE_UP AS
    (
    SELECT ID
        , Val
        , LEFT([1], CHARINDEX('.', [1], 0)-1) AS [Year]
        , [2] AS [Month]
    FROM CTE_Split AS S
        PIVOT (MAX(StringPart) FOR ordinal IN ([1], [2])) AS pvt 
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE_Up 


Thank you Jonathan!!! Much appreciated for help
